# laravel variable in view with parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to send a parameter from view to controller. 
How to do this in the views blade and controllers ?

```
DB::table('news')->where('id', '=', 1)->get()
```

So everything works. But I would like it to look nicer. e.g

```
{{ $news->id='1' }}
```

This is my beginnings with laravel.

Comment: you want to send the view from the blade view to the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'ld suggest you try sending data to controller via route as mentioned in other answers. But if you still don't want route, try this method.

Make your controller `function` as static. Eg:

```
public static function newsFunc($id){ //** static

    $data = DB::table('news')->where('id','=', $id)->get();
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

In your `view` call

```
{{ \App\Http\Controllers\YourControllerName::newsFunc($news->id) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt look like a good idea to send any data FROM view TO controllers

But if you really need it, you can pass controller object to view and interact with it in blade file:

```
class CatalogController extends Controller 
{
    public function showNews()
    {
        return view('catalog.sections', [
            'controller' => $this,
        ]);
    }
}
```

your blade file:

```
<div>
    @php($controller->doSomething())
</div>
```

Comment: could you write something more? I can not do this. :(

Answer (score 0):

In your Blade template you can call a route like:

```
<a href="{{route('something',$news->id)}}"
```

And in your route file you declare this route:

```
Route::get('something/{id}','yourController@yourMethod');
```

In your controller you can retrieve it:

```
public function yourMethod($id){
  //here u can use $id
}
```

Comment: I know this, but I want to use this without routes.

Comment: well, this is the most convenient,secure and recommended way of doing it, whats the problem with using routes?

Comment: because he wants the main page to have selected news from the database. as I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

So this is something that you could do with another route.

So you can register your route like this:

`Route::get('/news/{id}', 'YourController@getNews');`

And then your controller would have a method:

```
public function getNews($id) {
    $news = DB::table('news')->where('id', '=', 1)->first();
    return view('your-view', compact('news'));
}
```

And in your view to pass the id you would have something like:

`<a href="/news/1">Go to first</a>`

Hope that helps!